# Start mining in Ethereum Wallet

Tags: mining, ethereum-wallet-dapp, mac-osx

In Ethereum Wallet (TEST-NET) on macOS, under the **Develop** menu there is an item "Start mining (Testnet only)".

After clicking on it, how do I know anything is happening? There is no visual feedback? Nothing changes in the UI, and the menu item does not switch to "stop mining ...".

I'm not sure if it's bad a design or a bug, I have no idea if it works.

Comment: I have the same problem, I've filed git issue, please upvote https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2736

Answer (score 2):

Actually it doesn't works for me and probably you have the same problem. I only can advise you to open the terminal and type: `$ geth attach` and after it you can start mining directly from your terminal with the command: `$ miner.start(2)` 
It starts miner with 2 threads and if you want to stop mining you can type: `$ miner.stop()`.
It should help you with the mining

Answer (score 1):

If mining starts successfully, you get a mining icon with a number (such as 999 H/s) representing your hashrate, somewhere near the block number.